Where is azure pipelines tasks logs are getting stored in agent
What We Need
In azure release pipelines logs,  there is one link get generated in task log output i want to use it as a variable in next tasks.
I was thinking to parse it from the logs but unable to find the logs in agent.

How i can solve this issue. Where the logs are getting stored in agent in which directory?
i have checked the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) but could not find the logs.

Which task(s) are you using? There must be an easier way to do what you want, without having to parse the logs. Please edit your post explaining exactly what you're trying to do.

Thanks @RuiJarimba for quick response, i am using ACCELQ Azure CI Connect
task. A test report link is generated in tasks logs i want to use that link as a variable.

I'm afraid I can't help you with that given that is a custom task. I'd try to reach out to ACEQL somehow and see if there is an easy way to get the results link - maybe it is set as an output variable.

You can use the REST API Timeline - Get in the pipeline to get the detail of the pipeline. In the response of the Timeline- Get, we can find the log url of the tasks. Then we can get the log of the task to find the result link you need.
Here is my test sample yaml:
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: |
    echo "Testing"
    echo "Results link: https://dev.azure.com/"
    echo "Need to abort? ..."
  displayName: "Runtests"

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $orgname="your org name"
      $projectname="your project name"

      $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/$projectname/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=7.1"
      $TimelineResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      
      $loglink = $TimelineResponse.records | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "Runtests" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty log | Select-Object -ExpandProperty url
      Write-Output "The log link of task Run tests is  $loglink"

      $log = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $loglink -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}
      
      $Resultslink = ($log | Select-String -Pattern "Results link: (.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
      Write-Output "Results link is $Resultslink"

Test result:


thank you so much @Miao Tian-MSFT
it perfectly working. It solved my issue.
